# No consigo filtrar desde un select

Tags: javascript, dom, filtro, events

Partiendo de este codigo HTML necesito crear un filtro para que funcione mi select, me filtre el array de objetos que tengo y me pinte en el dom los objetos filtrados.
No sé qué estoy haciendo mal.
Cada vez que selecciono un valor en el select, en lugar de filtrarme, me quita todos los elementos filtrables.

código HTML

```
<form id="filter-options">
<h3>Filtros de búsqueda</h3>
<div class="seller_filter">
  <label class="seller" for="seller">Vendedores</label>
  <select name="seller" id="seller">
    <option disabled selected>Filtrar por tienda</option>
    <option value="1">Maui</option>
    <option value="2">Elisa</option>
    <option value="3">Phoebo</option>
    <option value="Paula">Paula</option>
  </select>
</div>
</form>
```

codigo Javascript

```
let selectValue = "";

const onOptionSelected = (event) => {
  selectValue = event.target.value;

  const filteredProductsBySeller = products.filter((product) => {
  return product.seller == selectValue;
});

productsArticle.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < filteredProductsBySeller.length; i++) {
    productsArticle.innerHTML += `<div class="div_products">
  <img class="product_img" src="${filteredProductsBySeller[i].image}" alt="${filteredProductsBySeller[i].name}"/>
  <h3>${filteredProductsBySeller[i].name}</h3>
  <p>${filteredProductsBySeller[i].price}€</p>
  <p>${filteredProductsBySeller[i].seller}</p>
  </div>`;
    document.body.appendChild(productsArticle);
  }
};

const selectElement = document.querySelector("#seller");
selectElement.addEventListener("change", onOptionSelected);
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `products` en tu código?

Comment: Buenas Paula, no te funciona porque products no existe. Y estás haciendo un filter de una variable indefinida.
Deberías de declarar un array de products con los values del select, es decir, con: 1,2,3, paula, en este caso. Entiendo que lo habrás puesto para hacer pruebas, pero Paula mejor sustituirlo por un 4. 
Y con productsArticle te pasará algo similar, tienes que definirla a un string vacio.

Comment: Gracias! Realmente creo que me expresé fatal. Lo siento!

Esa parte está hecha, lo que quiero es conseguir que al usar ese select en el navegador, mi código me filtre los artículos de mi tienda de un array  de objetos "products" por su categoría seller (cada uno de los seller son una opción del select). Actualmente conseguía que la consola me lo imprimiera, pero he creado millones de veces un .filter() y solo he conseguido funciones en la consola y no en el dom.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se describe en la pregunta "*A partir de este código HTML, necesito crear un filtro para que mi select funcione*  **...**" no tiene sentido.

El select no tiene la capacidad de filtrar, lo que puedes hacer es iterar los valores contenidos.

En la primera parte, debes seleccionar el elemento select:

```
var camp_select = document.getElementById("seller");
```

Simplemente devolver el elemento no cumple con el objetivo, se necesita una acción para eso se utiliza addEventListener.

```
camp_select.addEventListener("change", function(){});
```

El change, cada vez que haya un evento en el select y ocurra una modificación, se ejecutará.

Con selectedIndex se mostrará el índice de la opción seleccionada.

```
var ind_selec = campo_select.selectedIndex;
```

El options devuelve una colección de objetos HTMLOptionElement, se utiliza para acceder al índice:

```
 var txt = campo_select.options[indice_selecionado].innerHTML;
```

código completo:

```js
var camp_select = document.getElementById("seller");
camp_select.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var ind_selec = camp_select.selectedIndex;
  var txto = camp_select.options[ind_selec].innerHTML;
  console.log(txto);
});
```

```html
<form id="filter-options">
<h3>Filtros de búsqueda</h3>
<div class="seller_filter">
  <label class="seller" for="seller">Vendedores</label>
  <select name="seller" id="seller">
    <option disabled selected>Filtrar por tienda</option>
    <option value="1">Maui</option>
    <option value="2">Elisa</option>
    <option value="3">Phoebo</option>
    <option value="Paula">Paula</option>
  </select>
</div>
</form>
```